# Bash script can't find file in /opt and gives strange error message

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use a simple bash script that uses a script in `/opt`

```
#!/bin/bash
pvpython=/opt/paraviewopenfoam54/bin/pvbatch
script_path=save_contours.py
$pvpython $script_path
```

The file `pvbatch` does exist, however when I try to run the script I get this strange error message which feels like it is missing some characters:

```
: No such file or directoryaviewopenfoam54/bin/pvbatch
```

The Ubuntu I am using is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS inside a *Windows subsystem for Linux*. What could cause this error message?

When I run `ls -al pvbatch` in `/opt/paraviewopenfoam54/bin` I get

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 84200 May 29  2018 pvbatch
```

`cat pvbatch` returns an error message

```
cat: write error: Input/output error
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing about your batch file tag could cause it. It's not a batch file.

Comment: Bash I meant bash... I am sorry.

Comment: The "No such file or directory" part is definitely due to DOS carriage returns in your script file; this is a common FAQ [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `cat` cant read the file which is strange!

My first thought is that there is an issue with the file itself. where was the file created? I see that it is under `/opt/paraviewopenfoam54/bin` which is a linux managed folder, did you create and edit the file using vim in WSL or did you create it in windows somehow with VS Code or the like?

Let me just check that you are not creating and editing files in windows directly in the /opt folder inside the %LOCALAPPDATA% folders. If the file was created in this method you risk corrupting the WSL installation. [Dont Edit WSL files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: The file was actually created when installing OpenFOAM inside the Linux subsystem. I never touched it manually, neither using vim nor from Windows.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, can you vim the file? i would look into the error `cat: write error: Input/output error` as if you cant pipe the file to cat chances are you cant run it either.

Comment: I just opened `pvbatch` in vim and it basically only consists of repeating `^@`. What does that mean and how did this happen?

Comment: sounds like a corrupt file, i cant say how it got like this, as my answer states one possible way is if it gets edited from windows, but since you didnt do this i dont know. Maybe try reinstalling OpenFOAM whatever this is, can you get in touch with the devs responsible for that app/service

Answer (score -1):

When using WSL I commonly find issues and especially this `Input/output error` issue whenever I create a file directly from windows into the Linux filesystem. There are essentially three main ways to fix this specific issue: (these are not steps but rather separate solutions)

-Restart your Ubuntu terminal

-Restart your entire computer

-Delete the file directly from Windows, `touch` the file, then overwrite the file with the old one

For a more scalable solution, I recommend leaving the file within the windows system and only working within the Linux system within Linux.

Comment: I find this answer poor and confused, especially the windowish advice of "restart the computer". Why not reinstall the os?